# Are '.onion' websites safer/better than 'normal' clearnet websites like '.com'?

Tags: darknet, clear-net

This might is a bad question, but I'm using Tor to still access clearnet websites like `duckduckgo.com` and since there is also an onion version, here's my question:

Is there a difference between using `duckduckgo.com` and the onion version `duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion` (previously `3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion`) in privacy and safety?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Using the .onion links can only increase your security or do no harm (the security stay the same). Use them as much as possible.

Long answer: It depends on what your threat model is. If it includes someone have already hacked your computer (or the website have some of your private data but may betray on you), then no the .onion sites are not and won't be any safer than the clearnet version. But if your threat model only includes not logged-in websites stealing your data or some three-letter agency ease dropping on your metadata. Then yes, the the .onion are a lot safer. This is what Tor is built for - stopping people knowing who you are, who you are talking to and what you are talking about.